# Upgrading from Xcode 3.2 to Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

If I upgrade from Xcode 3.2 to Xcode 4 will the iPhone App I've recently built still run or is it likely to break? I'm using Snow Leopard.

Comment: Should be fine - the only warning you will encounter when re-building your project will be whether to enable snapshots or not for the project. These can be viewed and used through Window -> Organizer and then under the Projects tab.

Comment: Thanks. I have to upgrade really as my iPhone is now iOS5 and I want to be able to test the App on there. Xcode 3.2 won't allow testing on my device and keeps throwing up an error - it's too new I suspect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When upgrading Xcode versions make sure you have backed up the project just to be sure. It most likely will go smooth, but sometimes upgrading version might cause problems with linking, libraries, etc. I absolutely recomend the upgrade, as 4 is much better to use than 3.2. Just make sure you have time to fix bugs, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

All will works fine. You can develope to both iOS5 and iOS4 as well.